# C# regex getting only a matching result

Tags: c#, regex

I'm trying to learn Regex to do spell checking, never used before.

My practice regex is:

```
\b[Yy]ou(?:'re|'ll)?\b
```

which I'm testing against:

```
"You you yyou Yyou yYou youu yoou you'll You're You'ree"
```

Results:

```
"You", "you", "you'll", "You're", "You"('ree)
```

It almost works as I want, how can I make it so the "You" in "You'ree" doesn't get returned as a match?

Thanks,
Darren.

Comment: Try whitespace boundaries, `@"(?<!\S)[Yy]ou(?:'(?:re|ll))?(?!\S)"`

Comment: Thank you @WiktorStribiżew this appears to achieve exactly what I'm wanting. :)

Answer (score 0):

You can add a negative look ahead to avoid the apostrophe as a word boundary

```
\b[Yy]ou(?:'re|'ll)?(?!')\b
```

You'd need to add any other special characters to that negative look ahead since `\b` only thinks letters, numbers, and underscores are words.  So maybe something like the following would be even better.

```
\b[Yy]ou(?:'re|'ll)?(?!['-.,])\b
```

Add whatever special charters you want to consider as part of a word.

Answer (score 0):

Use a negative look ahead.  This will exclude any that follows the apostrophe that is not in a group.

```
\b[Yy]ou(?:'re|'ll)?(?!')\b
```

Comment: This works also. Thank you :)